# Not able to install nuklear library

Tags: opengl, go, package

I am trying to install `nuklear` library on `Debian Stable Linux` with instructions from https://github.com/golang-ui/nuklear

However, I am getting following error:

```
$ go get github.com/golang-ui/nuklear/nk

# github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.2/glfw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have following libGL files on my system:

```
me@mycomp:/usr/lib$ find | grep libGL\.so 

./i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
./i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

At one page, it was suggested to install mesa-dev, but I cannot make out how to choose between following which are available:

```
Package                 Installed       Previous        Now             State
=======================-===============-===============-===============-=====
libegl1-mesa-dev        N/A             13.0.6-1+b2     13.0.6-1+b2    
libgl1-mesa-dev         N/A             13.0.6-1+b2     13.0.6-1+b2    
libgles1-mesa-dev       N/A             13.0.6-1+b2     13.0.6-1+b2    
libgles2-mesa-dev       N/A             13.0.6-1+b2     13.0.6-1+b2    
libglu1-mesa-dev        N/A             9.0.0-2.1       9.0.0-2.1      
libglw1-mesa-dev        N/A             8.0.0-1.1       8.0.0-1.1
```

How can this problem be corrected?

Edit: 
The problem got corrected with following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0  /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Comment: You probably don't have to choose, just install all of them. EGL is low level, GL is what you want, gles1/2 you can skip because that's for ES, u is util and w is (I think) for windowing. Depending on your GPU, though, there might be an official driver for linux you can install instead.

Comment: Above error got corrected after creation of a link: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0  /usr/lib/libGL.so`