# Nuklear GUI demo not running

Tags: user-interface, go, package

I am trying to run demo file at https://github.com/golang-ui/nuklear/blob/master/cmd/nk-example-sdl2/main.go but I am getting following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./nk_nuclear_gui.go:72: undefined: MustAsset
./nk_nuclear_gui.go:126: undefined: flag
./nk_nuclear_gui.go:129: undefined: flag
```

I believe MustAsset is part of [Reckon package](https://godoc.org/github.com/zulily/reckon#MustAsset) which I installed, but error persists. Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Edit: Both commands `go build main.go` and `go run main.go` give this error. Even `go build` without any filename is also giving this error as discussed in comments.

I had encountered [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260895/not-able-to-install-nuklear-library) while installing nuklear package.

I am running following version on Debian Stable Linux:

```
go version go1.7.4 linux/amd64
```

I installed latest version (`go version go1.10.3 linux/amd64`) from https://golang.org/doc/install but the error persists.

Edit: The directory structure of `go` directory is as follows:

```
$ tree -d
.
├── pkg
│   └── linux_amd64
│       └── github.com
│           ├── golang-ui
│           │   └── nuklear
│           └── xlab
└── src
    └── github.com
        ├── go-gl
        │   ├── gl
        │   │   ├── all-core
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v2.1
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v3.1
        │   │   │   └── gles2
        │   │   ├── v3.2-compatibility
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v3.2-core
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v3.3-compatibility
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v3.3-core
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.1-compatibility
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.1-core
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.2-compatibility
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.2-core
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.3-compatibility
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.3-core
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.4-compatibility
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.4-core
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.5-compatibility
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.5-core
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   ├── v4.6-compatibility
        │   │   │   └── gl
        │   │   └── v4.6-core
        │   │       └── gl
        │   └── glfw
        │       ├── scripts
        │       ├── v3.0
        │       │   └── glfw
        │       ├── v3.1
        │       │   └── glfw
        │       │       └── glfw
        │       │           ├── deps
        │       │           │   ├── EGL
        │       │           │   ├── GL
        │       │           │   ├── glad
        │       │           │   └── KHR
        │       │           ├── include
        │       │           │   └── GLFW
        │       │           └── src
        │       └── v3.2
        │           └── glfw
        │               └── glfw
        │                   ├── deps
        │                   │   ├── glad
        │                   │   ├── KHR
        │                   │   ├── mingw
        │                   │   └── vulkan
        │                   ├── include
        │                   │   └── GLFW
        │                   └── src
        ├── golang-ui
        │   └── nuklear
        │       ├── assets
        │       ├── cmd
        │       │   ├── nk-android
        │       │   │   ├── android
        │       │   │   │   └── jni
        │       │   │   └── assets
        │       │   ├── nk-example
        │       │   │   └── assets
        │       │   └── nk-example-sdl2
        │       │       └── assets
        │       └── nk
        └── xlab
            └── closer
                └── cmd
                    ├── example
                    ├── example-error
                    ├── example-fatalln
                    └── example-panic
```

Comment: How did you run the code?

Comment: If you are using `go run main.go` this is expected. `MustAsset` is defined in `bindata.go` (which is commonly generated by go-bindata). You should try run `go build` and then run the executable built.

Comment: Above errors come with both `go build` and `go run` commands.

Comment: run `go build` without any training arguments.

Comment: `go build` command without any arguments (file name or anything else) also give same error. I installed `go-bindata` but the error is persisting.

Comment: I doubt your repo is compromised. Can you find `MustAsset` in `bindata.go`?

Comment: The function is there in this file: `func MustAsset(name string) []byte {
 a, err := Asset(name)
 if err != nil {
  panic("asset: Asset(" + name + "): " + err.Error())
 }

 return a
}
`

Comment: I cannot understand this down vote.

Comment: run `go clean; go build` and if that shows the same error, I would like to see you directory structure (run `dir` or `ls` or `tree`)

Comment: `go clean` does not work. It completed without any msg. Same error with `go build` after `go clean`. I just have this main.go file in a general folder named `~/0-golang`. I have not made any directory structure for this file. Are you asking about `go` directory structure where `golang-ui/nuklear` package is installed?

Comment: @mso This seems to be the problem. You need to copy all files, sub-directorries and anything else into your directory, not just `main.go`.

Comment: Pl see the directory structure of my `go` folder in my question above.

Comment: No, you need to keep everything where you run the `go build`. Everything, from `main.go` to `bindata.go` and `asset` sub-directory. Better if you run it in its orignal directory.

Comment: I downloaded `bindata.go` and `util.go` from website example page to the `~/0-golang/nuk-demo` folder along with `main.go` and now it works. It created an executable named `nuk-demo`. I did not touch `go` folder (tree shown in question) where `nuklear` package is installed. Is that OK? Thanks for your help. You may enter these comments as an answer and I will accept it with an upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go, programs (and package) are based on directory. So very often, multiple source files complement each other. In this case, the `MustAsset` is defined in `bindata.go`. Therefore isolating `main.go` raises an error. You can read more about Go's source file organization here: https://golang.org/doc/code.html